# ITunes takes forever to load a song preview

Tags: itunes, itunes-store

The Itunes store takes forever to load a 1.5 minute song preview, and in the middle it still gives 'Opening URL Buffer stream' dialog box. I have tried `defaults write com.apple.iTunes buffer-stream-size 128000`, tried 256000 and 64000 but I still get the same problem. My internet connection is not to blame. How do I speed up the loading?

Edit: This is itunes version  on a 13 inch macbook pro running Yosemite 10.10.4. App store takes really long as well to load pages.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried resetting your iTunes store cache? (Preference, Advanced)

Comment: Yes but it hasn't changed it. Well maybe it has but it's still slow